# Trying to write and read from the same com port, successful at writing, but failing at reading. Wat do?

Tags: java, serial-port, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to get some data from the com port, the same one I'm writing data on, but it proves hard to read. I managed to find a simple code piece to read it, but now, I only read zeros. What could be the cause?

I'm sending my code below, with explanation of their intended usages.

```
private void ReadFromComPortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    try {
        String text = EmulatorInput.getText();
        sendData(text, "COM4");
        String out_Text = Arrays.toString(read());
        EmulatorOutput.setText(out_Text);
        System.out.println(out_Text);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is a JButton, method name and parameter has been created by NetBeans. Code firsts gets a text from the input panel as a string, sends it with a com port name, connects to that port, and opens input/output streams by it, then writes the string it took from the input panel to the OutputStream. Then, I create a new string, named `out_Text` and use `read()` method to read the data from port.

Here is the read method;

```
private byte[] read() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
    int total = 0, read = 0;
    while (total <= 16 && (read = input.read(buffer, total, 16-total)) > 0)  {
        total += read;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

After the first method I posted uses `read()` to converge it into a string that I can print as a byte array, I end up with only a byte of zeros.

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I'm very confused by this, because I'm sure I write to the port. I even monitored what I write, and can see that as I use the program to write data to the com port, the data it received increases.

If there is something that is unclear or if you need more of the code, please contact via comments.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Always check your comm port settings. Baud, data bits, parity, etc. Then make sure you're sending a command that actually generates a response from the target.

Comment: I've monitored the COM port I opened, to see if I was sending some data. Eventually, I do, since whenever I run
`echo message > COM#` (do mind that # stands for the COM port number) it shows that bytes are getting through. I did that in the java code too, and confirmed that I was sending data. The exact problem is, I can't get into that while on the second code piece I sent. Because it always reads 0 from the input (InputStream type, created as `input = port.getInputStream()` Also, I got my baudrate at 9600, databits at 8 with no parity, and got 1 stopbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I've tried the same operation with [jSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/), and managed to write again. However, I was still not able to read. Then I noticed, that I was creating **pairs** of com ports. So, simply, I started to write to one port, and received the data from the other port of the pair. It worked like a charm. I'm not sure if the same idea is valid for **rxtx** libraries, but because **jSSC**'s documents are descriptive, and because it's easy to use, I switched to it, and the way I did worked. You can find a detailed explanation of how I did below, without the code.

**PreStep** > I had COM6 and COM7 intact when I started this.

**Step1** > Opened both ports via jSSC's methods. I constructed them as SerialPort, and then set their parameters (BaudRate, DataBits, etc.).

**Step2** > I started to take inputs from console, and write them to the COM6. When I monitored the port, and the bytes in it, it was changing each time I sent an input.

**Step3** > Each time I would press "Enter" to send the input, I'd invoke a reading method from COM7 object, and it would send a byte array to the console (Via Arrays.toString(byte[] array) method).

I don't know why I can't read from the same port as I write, but alas, my problem is solved. Thanks for your time to read this answer. If you have any questions, please post them under this one as a comment.